# Usage of @Autowired in JUnit-Tests

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

I am using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner in my unit test and the test can access autowired beans (mocked services) properly.

How ever it tests a Job that also talks to the services. The job also has the beans autowired.

Sadly inside the "new Job().execute(...)" call from within the test, the autowired services inside the Job are null.

Can anyone suggest/guess what is going wrong !?

Comment: So Job itself is a separate class that needs to be mocked in your situation.

Comment: `InjectMocks` might be an answer: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances not created and managed by Spring will not be injected with their dependencies by Spring (unless you apply some [AspectJ magic](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)).

As the `Job` instance is created by the application, you will have to manually inject its dependencies. Simply set mocks, or autowire the beans required by `Job` in the test class and pass them to the newly created instance.